# 'react-i18next: withNamespaces is not a function' when testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using react-i18next on a typescript project.
I was using `translate()` HOC but it's deprecated so I've migrate to `withNamespaces()`. Everything used to work pretty well.

Now everything keeps working fine when I start the app, but it fails badly during the tests:

```
FAIL  src/containers/MainMenu/MainMenu.test.tsx
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: react_i18next_1.withNamespaces is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/AppMenu/AppMenu.tsx:17:35)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/AppMenu/index.ts:3:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/MainMenu/MainMenu.tsx:18:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/MainMenu/MainMenu.test.tsx:42:18)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Here's my `AppMenu` component:

My app is a pretty standard Create-React-App install.

```
import {TranslationFunction} from 'i18next';
import * as React from 'react';
import {withNamespaces, WithNamespaces} from 'react-i18next';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export interface IAppMenuProps extends WithNamespaces {
    items: IAppMenuItem[];
    t: TranslationFunction;
}

function AppMenu({items, t}: IAppMenuProps): JSX.Element {
    return (
        // ... some stuff here
    );
}

export default withNamespaces()(AppMenu);
```

And the test file which fails:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import {create} from 'react-test-renderer';
import MainMenu from './MainMenu';

describe('MainMenu', () => {
    test('Snapshot test', async () => {
        const comp = create(
            <Router>
                <MainMenu />
            </Router>
        );

        expect(comp).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

My app is a standard Create-React-App install, so tests are running with jest.

Can't find what I'm missing to get this working and why it's failing during tests and not at runtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty stupid issue.. I forgot I had an auto mock file for react-i18next.
So I just needed to change `translate` function to `withNamespaces` in this mock.

Comment: Could you post your mock please because I have same issue

Comment: @MohammadFared My mock is too long to post in comments, but you can find an example in official repo: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/test-jest/src/__mocks__/react-i18next.js